# What is most common way of shell scripting in Clojure?

Tags: shell, clojure

I found great examples of what Im looking for here : http://hugoduncan.org/post/2010/shell_scripting_in_clojure_with_pallet.xhtml

But seems like this "Pallet" is not what it was earlier... it says "Pallet is platform for agile and programmatic automation of infrastructure in the cloud, on server racks or directly on virtual machines. Pallet provides cloud provider and operating system independence, and allows for an unprecedented level of customization." - it's not what I want. I need just shell scripting.

Is there something alike in Clojure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part of Pallet that translates clojure s-expressions into shell script is called *Stevedore* and it is available as a separate library: https://github.com/pallet/stevedore

Documentation on both Pallet and Stevedore on the Pallet website might not always be complete or accurate (the docs are a bit behind current code), so it might require a bit of puzzling.

Out of curiosity, what kind of shell scripting would you like to do in Clojure?

Comment: Making some automate jobs (running custom commands (most of git commands) in various folders) by timers.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your problem, stevedore might be overkill. In any case - stevedore only translates clojure to shell script, it doesn't execute it. If you only need to start/stop processes, it might be better to use java's ProcessBuilder (you could create a little clojure wrapper around it): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 3):

If *Stevedore* seems overkill for your particular case you can make simple clojure scripts and run them like any shell scripts using 'lein-exec' Leiningen plug-in.

http://www.unexpected-vortices.com/clojure/brief-beginners-guide/standalone-scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this page and I noticed that the answers are all **way** out of date.

Just a month ago, the Reddit user [didibus](https://www.reddit.com/user/didibus/) posted an excellent guide to [r/Clojure](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/): [Scripting in Clojure, many great options!](https://www.reddit.com/r/Clojure/comments/e3jdpb/scripting_in_clojure_many_great_options/).

I hope it’s OK if I quote some of that guide here:

> I'd recommend looking at all the awesome scripting options for Clojure:
>
> - http://inlein.org/
> - https://joker-lang.org/
> - https://github.com/borkdude/babashka
> - https://github.com/dundalek/closh
> - https://github.com/anmonteiro/lumo
> - https://planck-repl.org/
> - https://gist.github.com/ericnormand/6bb4562c4bc578ef223182e3bb1e72c5
>
> Honestly, scripting is just a solved problem for Clojure in my opinion. At this point. There's even too many good options probably.

They then share fairly extensive commentary on most of these options. It’s an excellent guide and I recommend reading it in full.

For what it’s worth, I myself like [the last option](https://gist.github.com/ericnormand/6bb4562c4bc578ef223182e3bb1e72c5); it’s a clever technique for writing a shell script in “plain old Clojure” and running it via [the Clojure CLI tools](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli).